# Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments

I have the following code:

```
 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount,
      'currency' => 'cad',
            'capture' => 'false',

      'description'=>  $courseTitle

  ));


$charge_json = $charge->__toJSON();

echo $charge_json['id'];
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($charge_json); 
 echo "</pre>";


}
```

where the intent is to grab whats on the green below:
[image]

but I receive the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'
```

I would like to later use that variable in a mysql query

Comment: By calling `__toJSON`, you are _making_ the object into a string.

Comment: its not present but it is with the intention of using that variable in a mysql query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a JSON string as far as I can tell.

You need to convert it to an array or object using [**json_decode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$array = json_decode($charge_json, true);
$object = json_decode($charge_json);
```

For an array, you access it like you are.

For an object, you access it like: `$object->id`

If Stripe provides a way to retrieve it as an object or array already, you should use that.

Answer (score 2):

$charge is already an object so you could just grab $charge->id

```
echo $charge->id
```

would print the charge id.

calling toJSON converts it to string, so string[string] is not valid php.